# Kibana : Is it possible to create interactive forms

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Is it possible to create interactive forms in Kibana Dashboard? For example where a user can enter something and that is fed to a search query. I know it is relatively easy to create this in Splunk. Right now, the onlyinteractive chart i could find in Kibana is the Table.